# Set value as age instead of date of birth in a datagridview column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridview in a windows forms. I have a field DOB (Date Of Birth) as DateTime, I want to display Age instead of displaying the DOB.
Example: DOB is 13.06.2007 I want to display 10. 
I have a method that calculates the age from the DOB, how can i assign it to the coulmn. ?

```
private void bindToGrid(DataTable dtb)
{
   using (dtb)
   {
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dtb;

       dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Age";
       dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Age";
       dataGridView1.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "DOB";
    }
}

public static string getAge(DateTime dob)
{
    var today = DateTime.Today;
    var age = today.Year - dob.Year;

    if (dob > today.AddYears(-age))
        age--;
    return age.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need a `using` statement for the datatable, since it doesn't implement `IDisposable`

Comment: If the DOB column is not displayed... how would the user be able to change its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `DataGridView` has a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` such that the “DOB” column in the `DataTable` is of type `DateTime`, then you will not be able to put an `int` “Age” value into those cells of the `DataGridView` because this will throw a `DataError` since the single `int` (Age) value is not in a valid `DateTime` format.

Since “Age” is a calculated value, and we can always calculate this value based on the birth date, then in seems unnecessary to go through the trouble of changing the current `DataTable` `dtb` “DOB” column to an “Age” column. In addition altering the table may affect other code if the altered table is used elsewhere and expects a DOB field. Therefore, it makes sense to keep this “Age” column separate from the `DataTable` and simply ADD this “Age” column to the `DatGridView`.

To keep things simple, and to get you started, I would recommend you leave the “DOB” column in the `DataTable` alone for the time being and simply ADD this “Age” column to the `DataGridView` NOT the `DataTable`.

Assuming the `DataGridView` is already filled with data `dataGridView1.DataSource = dtb;`…The method below `AddAgeColumn` adds the “Age” column then loops through the `DataGridView` rows and sets the “Age” columns value using the `getAge` method in the original post. You would call this method right after the grid is filled with data.

```
private void AddAgeColumn() {
  try {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Age", "Age");
    DateTime curBD;
    int curAge;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvr in dataGridView1.Rows) {
      if (!dgvr.IsNewRow) {
        curBD = (DateTime)dgvr.Cells["DOB"].Value;
        curAge = getAge(curBD);
        dgvr.Cells["Age"].Value = curAge;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

This should display both the “DOB” column and the “Age” column in the grid. The only problem is if the user either adds a new row or changes a “DOB” value, then the “Age” column may not reflect this change. To fix this, we simply need to add a method that looks for when the “DOB” value changes and when it does, simply update the “Age” column. The `DataGridView`’s `CellValueChanged` event will work for indicating if the “DOB” value is changed. A wired up example is below:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
  if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DOB") {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DOB"].Value.ToString())) {
      DateTime newDOB = (DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["DOB"].Value;
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Age"].Value = getAge(newDOB); ;
    } else {
      dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Age"].Value = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Lastly, this will work however, if the user is running the program at 11:59 P.M, and one of the “DOB” values is the current date… then when the clock reaches 12:00 A.M. the AGE will not reflect this change since the “DOB” value has not changed. You may consider a method to update the “Age” values and simply run it if this situation occurs. Hope this makes sense and helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I need. To show the Age from the DOB. I will not edit the DOB. The edit will be in another form, and I will call the load again when the other form closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to introduce a new property:

1. add a new property to the object that binds to the datagridview table, call it "Age"
2. make DOB property not browsable by adding an attribute [Browserable(false)], so it won't visually appear in the table
3. put logic in 'Age' setter to update DOB value whenever Age value is changed.

Comment: But hey ! If you change the Age value, how would you chose the DOB accordingly ? I mean if I set my Age to 40, would you set the DOB to 13/06/1977 or 20/10/1977 or any of the 365 days that would make me 40 today ? I don't think the OP wants to change the DOB from Age, but only display it.

Comment: There are DOB's, and I want to calculate the age from the DOB. I have the method that can do that. please read my question and look at the code